# how can I transform the following css object correctly

Tags: css, transform

I have a `div` object designed with `css` and `transform`; but I actually now need it the other way round. I tried so many ways, nothing works.

Does anybody have any useful tip?

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .blau80 {
    background: #006d68;
    height: 350px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform: skew(-80deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-80deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-80deg);
  }
</style>
<div class="blau80"></div>
```

Kind regards
Maya

How it should look

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tried it on codepen. Works for me.

Key change: `transform-origin:100% 0;`

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .blau80 {
        background:#006d68;
        height:350px;
        transform-origin:100% 0;    
        transform: skew(-80deg);
       -webkit-transform:skew(-80deg);
        -ms-transform:skew(-80deg);
    }

    </style>
    <div class="blau80"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `scaleY(-1)` transformation works. What this does is makes a symetric of your div on the X axis.

```css
    .blau80 {
        background:#006d68;
        height:350px;
        -webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;
        -ms-transform-origin:100% 100%;
        transform-origin:100% 100%;    
        transform: skew(-80deg) scaleY(-1);
       -webkit-transform:skew(-80deg) scaleY(-1);
        -ms-transform:skew(-80deg) scaleY(-1);
    }
```

```html
<div class="blau80"></div>
```